# C# How to store value and check with database?

Tags: c#

I am doing random question from database, but now i want to store the value and the question ID and check with database see weather the answer is correct or not? How can i store the value from radio button and textbox after i click on submit button?

this is my coding for random question

```
public void showquestion()
{
    string Category = "10-20";

    string query = "SELECT top 10 * FROM question where Age_group= '"+ Category +"' order by newid()";
    if (question.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, question.connection);
        question.rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (question.rdr.Read())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();

                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.Text = Environment.NewLine + count + ") " +  question.rdr["Question"].ToString();
                    label.ID = "Qustion_" + question.rdr["ID"].ToString() + "Label";
                    cell.Controls.Add(label);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    StoreQuestion[ArrayCount] = label.ID.ToString();
                    count++;
                    ArrayCount++;
                }
                table1.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            switch (Convert.ToInt32(question.rdr["question_type"]))
            {
                case 1:
                    Database question1 = new Database();
                    if (question1.OpenConnection() == true)
                    {
                        string query1 = "SELECT * FROM Choice WHERE Question_ID= " + question.rdr["id"];
                        SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(query1, question1.connection);
                        question1.rdr = comm1.ExecuteReader();
                        while (question1.rdr.Read())
                            {

                                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                                {
                                    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

                                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();

                                        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
                                        radioButton.Text = question1.rdr["Choice"].ToString();
                                        radioButton.GroupName = question.rdr["Question"].ToString();
                                        radioButton.ID = question.rdr["Question"].ToString() + question1.rdr["Choice"].ToString();
                                        cell.Controls.Add(radioButton);
                                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                                    }
                                                  table1.Rows.Add(row);
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    question1.CloseConnection();
                    break;
                case 2://text box fill

                                for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                                {
                                    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

                                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                                        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
                                        textbox.ID = question.rdr["Question"].ToString();

                                        cell.Controls.Add(textbox);
                                        row.Cells.Add(cell);
                                    }
                                    table1.Rows.Add(row);
                                }
                    break;
            }
        }

        question.CloseConnection();

        protected void Submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: you could store the question value in the session, or you could save them to a database table. The database option would allow you to do a number of things with the answer data (such as compare with their previous attempts or compare with how others fared on average). If you would like an example please let me know.

Comment: How could i store the question value in the session? Can i have an example how to store it and compare?

Comment: I have added the answer below, notice the use of dictionary, this allows you to map questions and answers together, then you run a select on your database for each pair selecting the question based on its ID and check the answer

Comment: are all of your questions and answers being rendered on a single page or are you doing one question per page?

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class like so:

```
public class MySession
{
    public static MySession Instance
    {
        // this is the element you store the question and answer in by using MySession.Instance.QnsAndAnswer.Add(qnID, ansId);
        public Dictionary<QuestionID, AnswerID> QnsAndAnswers { get; set; }

        get 
        {
            MySession session = (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];

            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new MySession();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
            }
            return session;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not so understand about this. Could you help me to do an example on my coding?

Comment: this MySession class can be called from anywhere in your code and the data within it will retain its value, where I am using the dictionary you can use whatever datatype you like to store the ID's you want saved, then once the user has finished answering questions you can run through the data and check their results.